# Regex: why do I get empty string in result

Tags: javascript, regex

OK I'm not good at Regex. I want to split with delimiter ' while keeping it. What I want as output is

```
(3) ["'", "TEST", "'"]
```

When I use:

```
"'TEST'".split(/(['])/g);
```

Instead I get:

```
(5) ["", "'", "TEST", "'", ""]
```

It's almost what I want except I also get 2 empty strings. Why ?

Comment: maybe like this ? "'TEST'".replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)/g, "\n$1\n").split(/\n/)

Comment: @D.Seah thanks maybe usefull also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the trick by using a [positive lookahead and lookbehind](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/the-complicated-syntax-of-lookaheads-in-javascript-regular-expressions/):

```
> "'TEST'".split(/(?<=')(.+)(?=')/g)
["'", "TEST", "'"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex seems to be overkill for this purpose. Something like this works:

```
"'TEST'".split("'").map(str => (str.length) ? str : "'");
// [ "'", 'TEST', "'" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You end up with two empty strings in your array because the first `'` character separates an empty string at the beginning from the string `TEST`, while the second `'` character separates the string `TEST` from another empty string at the end.

---

You can just use [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
console.log("'TEST'".match(/'|[^']+/g));
```

Make sure you check for a `null` return value from `.match()`, but that is only possible with this particular regular expression when applied to an empty string.

Comment: Good suggestion, will try if it can cope with all my use cases.